# Maven needs to run everytime after a file changes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My problem: I have to run maven clean site everytime a file is changed so that Eclipse runs the new version... Can someone help me? It's quite annoying to run clean site everytime.

This is (partially) my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <slick2d.version>1.0.2</slick2d.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <json.plugin.version>1.1.1</json.plugin.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <findbugs.annotations.version>1.3.2</findbugs.annotations.version>

    <javadoc.plugin.version>2.10.3</javadoc.plugin.version>
    <checkstyle.plugin.version>2.17</checkstyle.plugin.version>
    <pmd.plugin.version>3.6</pmd.plugin.version>
    <findbugs.plugin.version>3.0.3</findbugs.plugin.version>
    <cobertura.plugin.version>2.7</cobertura.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- slick2D dependency -->
        <groupId>org.slick2d</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick2d-core</artifactId>
        <version>${slick2d.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- junit dependency -->
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- json dependency -->
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${json.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency> <!-- mockito dependency -->
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${findbugs.annotations.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> <!-- cobertura -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cobertura.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <instrumentation>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*/CoberturaIgnore.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>*/highscore/HighScore.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>*/pop/PopBehaviour.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>*/ui/*.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <ignoreMethodAnnotations>
                        <ignoreMethodAnnotation>spiceballs.CoberturaIgnore</ignoreMethodAnnotation>
                    </ignoreMethodAnnotations>
                </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- checkstyle -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- pmd -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${pmd.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- findbugs -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${findbugs.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> <!-- javadoc report -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- cobertura report -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cobertura.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- checkstyle report -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- pmd report -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${pmd.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin> <!-- findbugs report -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${findbugs.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: did you setup your Eclipse project to be a maven project?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes I have, when i import it, it definitely has to be imported as an existing maven project atleast.

Comment: did you try to update maven dependencies with <ALT>+<F5> from within eclipse?

Comment: Go to "Project" in menu and select "Build Automatically". Make sure you can see "M" on left hand of project. if this doesnt work then you might want to check maven  and JRE settings in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you working within your workspace locally, you can just run -- clean compile --goals. When you are finally done and pushing to higher environments- DEV/TEST/pre-prod, then you would run all the recommended goals for your project.
Look into this link for more details on what each goal does-

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html